# Joining and querying two tables with conflicting column names

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have two tables: **users** and **students**

Each table has an id and email column. I want to be able to search for emails from both tables. I can join the two tables where the IDs match like this:

```
SELECT users.email,students.email as student_email FROM users
INNER JOIN students ON users.id = students.id
```

I can't search the email column because they have the same column name (email). So if I try use `WHERE` it complains that the column (email) is ambiguous. If I try use **student_email** it complains that the column doesn't exist.

If the two tables didn't use an identical column name (email) then it would be fine when I use `WHERE`.

The only solution I can think of is to get all rows and then loop around them and search the email strings manually. This is extremely slow compared to using MySQL like this:

```
SELECT users.email,students.email as student_email FROM users
INNER JOIN students ON users.id = students.id
WHERE email LIKE '%test@email.com%' OR student_email LIKE '%test@email.com%'
```

But of course this doesn't work because `WHERE` looks for the original column names before the `SELECT`.

How can I get around this without getting all the rows and the looping it? Maybe it is a union, rather than a `JOIN`? I'm not sure...

Comment: `WHERE users.email LIKE '%test@email.com%' OR students.email LIKE '%test@email.com%'`. You can't use `student_email` in the WHERE clause, this is an alias for the column name, in the WHERE clause when you use `email` it's ambiguous  because 2 tables has emails to you have to prefix with the name of the table the same way you did in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the *qualified* column name.  I also recommend table aliases:

```
SELECT u.email, s.email as student_email
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     students s
     ON u.id = s.id
WHERE u.email LIKE '%test@email.com%' OR
      s.email LIKE '%test@email.com%';
```

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, you should always qualify all the column names.  Using abbreviations for the tables as table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks...I don't know why I didn't think to use the qualified name!